# Initialize vector using the ifelse function in R

Tags: r, statistics, simulation

I'm trying to run the next algorithm in R:

```
simulation <- function(n){
  f <- function(x){.7*h(x)+.3*g(x)}
  x <- vector("numeric", 2)
  w <- vector("numeric", 2)
  x0 <- c(3,3)
  for(i in 0:n){
    ifelse(i==0,w<-x0,w<-x) //After this line w=(3,3) (on the first iteration) 
    y <- rnorm(2, mean = w, sd = S1) //Also this line gives a non-zero value to y 
    alfa <- (f(y))/(f(w))
    ifelse(runif(1)<alfa,x<-y,x<-w) //Here the variables y and w are a two dimension zero vector. 
  }
  return(alfa[n])
}
```

I don't understand why at the second "ifelse" the vectors w and y are equal to (0,0). Maybe there is another way to initialize the vector x. But I don't get how the first "ifelse" works fine. Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: I had the same problem and I fix it updating my R version.

Comment: Thanks for the info! But still not working.

Comment: Could you add some expected output? Looks like the loop isnt necessary here

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the problem correctly you are trying to simulate a vector containing 2 values which in the function is named as alfa.

Also in each iteration w and y are not equal (0, 0) it is updating as you have stated in the function. The above function only returns the nth value of alfa.

alfa only has 2 elements in each iteration and return(alfa[n]) with return value from the last iteration only.

I have created two simple function named h and g assuming you will also have similar ones and defined sd as 1.

Made a small tweak to your query to get n number of vectors containing 2 elements each.

```
h <- function(x) {
  x ^ 2
}

g <- function(x) {
  x ^ 3
}

simulation <- function(n, S1 = 1, seed = 123){
  f <- function(x){.7*h(x)+.3*g(x)}
  x <- vector("numeric", 2)
  w <- vector("numeric", 2)
  x0 <- c(3, 3)
  for(i in 0:n){
    ifelse(i==0, w <- x0, w <- x) # After this line w=(3,3) (on the first iteration)
    set.seed(seed)
    y <- rnorm(2, mean = w, sd = S1) # Also this line gives a non-zero value to y 
    alfa <- (f(y))/(f(w))
    set.seed(seed + 1)
    ifelse(runif(1) < alfa, x <- y, x <- w) # Here the variables y and w are a two dimension zero vector.
    print(alfa)
  }
}

simulation(3)
```

Output from above query

```
[1] 0.5917627 0.8156456
[1] 0.5236186 0.8027823
[1] 0.4268981 0.7878858
[1] 0.2798218 0.7704123
```

Or else if you want to store the simulation in alfa and then return the complete alfa without printing each iteration then you can use the below function which creates a matrix for alfa:

```
simulation <- function(n, S1 = 1, seed = 123){
  f <- function(x){.7*h(x)+.3*g(x)}
  x <- vector("numeric", 2)
  w <- vector("numeric", 2)
  x0 <- c(3, 3)
  alfa <- matrix(0, nrow = n + 1, ncol = 2) # matrix of zeros
  for(i in 0:n){
    ifelse(i==0, w <- x0, w <- x) # After this line w=(3,3) (on the first iteration) 
    set.seed(seed)
    y <- rnorm(2, mean = w, sd = S1) # Also this line gives a non-zero value to y 
    alfa[i + 1, ] <- (f(y))/(f(w))
    set.seed(seed + 1)
    ifelse(runif(1) < alfa[i + 1, ], x <- y, x <- w) # Here the variables y and w are a two dimension zero vector.
  }
  return(alfa)
}

simulation(3)
```

Output from the above query

```
          [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.5917627 0.8156456
[2,] 0.5236186 0.8027823
[3,] 0.4268981 0.7878858
[4,] 0.2798218 0.7704123
```

I have used **alfa[i + 1, ]** since indexing in R starts from 1 and not 0.